# SQL Server Hanging after Insert Into Select

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, insert

Thanks for taking a look at this.

The issue has to do with the following sql query. Basically it recursively finds all pages underneath a certain page(master page), and then applies the master page's categories(looked up in the xref_pages_categories) to all of those pages.

Upon running the insert, querying the table for data that should have been inserted completely hangs.

If i run the query without the insert line, the results come back perfectly, like:

```
3245    490
3249    490
3252    490
```

But upon putting the insert in front of it and inserting, querying for pageid=3245 just hangs. Any ideas?

```
declare @page int;

set @page=3202;
begin transaction transki;

With FindAllPagesUnderneath(PageID, ParentID) as
(
    select id as PageID, ParentPageId as ParentID
    from pages where id=@page
    union all
    select id as PageID, ParentPageID as ParentID
    from pages p
    inner join FindAllPagesUnderneath mp on
    p.parentpageid=mp.PageID
)

insert into xref_pages_categories (PageID, CategoryID)


    --get records that definitely arent already in xref_pages_categories
select * from
(
    select distinct thegood.*
    from 
        (
        --get all pages under @page attached to new categoryid
        select distinct fap2.PageID, fapo.CategoryID
            from FindAllPagesUnderneath fap2
            cross join  (
                select fap.PageID,xpc.categoryid 
                from xref_pages_categories xpc
                inner join FindAllPagesUnderneath fap
                on fap.PageID=xpc.pageid
                where fap.pageid!=1 and
                fap.pageid!=1332
                and fap.parentid=1332
            ) fapo 
        where fap2.pageid !=@page
        ) thegood
        left outer join xref_pages_categories xpc
        on xpc.pageid = thegood.pageid
        where xpc.pageid is null
) final
```

Comment: You're not committing the transaction in your example. Is the error in the example or is the error the error? <g>

Comment: i believe in the answer, because when i committed without the temp table it did not work before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without looking into all of your code, at execution plans, or locking/blocking issues, you could try this hack:

create this table before the CTE:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempResults 
(
PageID         ...
,CategoryID    ...
)
```

INSERT into it and not `xref_pages_categories` (using the CTE SELECT)

then put this at the end of the code block:

```
insert into xref_pages_categories (PageID, CategoryID)
    SELECT PageID, CategoryID FROM #TempResults
```

This INSERT should run faster and hopefully not lock/block like they are doing now as part of the CTE.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. The insert executes right away without any issues, even without this hack. Its the select after the insert that hangs forever... if that helps at all. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: I consider everything from `WITH` up to and including `) final` to be the "INSERT".  Are you not using the CTE to populate the SELECT that feeds the INSERT with rows?  where is the select you are talking about?

Comment: I just ran a commit after running your code and it worked-- which it didnt do last night. I'm considering your initial answer (the temp table) to be what fixed it. Thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks!!!